# In Vue components, mounted: {this.init()}, raises an error : Unexpected token, expected {

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, echarts

When combining Vue and echarts, I wrote this in src/components/Chart.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Charts',
  data () {
    return {
      chart: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    style () {
      return {
        height: this.height,
        width: this.width
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: {this.init()},
  methods: {
    init () {
      this.chart = this.$echarts.init(document.getElementById(this.id))
      this.charts.setOption(this.option)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And when running `npm run dev`, it raised this:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                   22:51:02

 error  in ./src/components/Chart.vue

Syntax Error: this is a reserved word (57:12)

  55 |     }
  56 |   },
> 57 |   mounted: {this.init()},
     |             ^
  58 |   methods: {
  59 |     init () {
  60 |       this.chart = this.$echarts.init(document.getElementById(this.id))



 @ ./src/components/Chart.vue 4:0-105 5:0-118
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I've googled a lot, but didn't find an answer. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me.

Comment: It's simply invalid syntax. What are you trying to make happen there? What you have is defining a property using an object initializer ("object literal"), and a function call is not valid on its own in the body of an object initializer.

Answer (score 1):

`mounted` should reference a function literal, so try this

`mounted: function() { this.init() }`

Answer (score 1):

Same as you did with data, mounted should be a function:

```
mounted () {
    this.init()
},
```